# In Django Admin site password field changes when I edit the attribute of other widgets

Tags: django

In the default Django Admin site, the `Password` field shows how it is encrypted and there's a link to change it.

[image]

In my project I need to set some fields to LTR (because the site is in RTL), so this is what I do:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django import forms

from .models import CustomUser

# Register your models here.


class CustomUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['national_id'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['mobile_number'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})


@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = CustomUserForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (
            _('Personal info'),
            {
                'fields': (
                    'first_name',
                    'last_name',
                )
            },
        ),
        (
            _('Profile info'),
            {
                'fields': (
                    'national_id',
                    'mobile_number',
                    'home_address',
                    'work_address',
                )
            },
        ),
        (
            _('Permissions'),
            {
                'fields': (
                    'is_active',
                    'is_staff',
                    'is_superuser',
                    'is_verified',
                    'groups',
                    'user_permissions',
                ),
            },
        ),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
            },
        ),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'national_id', 'mobile_number')
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = (
        'groups',
        'user_permissions',
    )
```

But with that custom form, the `Password` field looks like this:

[image]

I have not touched anything related to it. Why it is changing?

EDIT:

As requested, here's the custom user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# Create your models here.


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email and password
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.password = make_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(
        _('verified status'),
        blank=True,
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user has verified their email address.'),
    )

    national_id = models.CharField(
        _('National ID'),
        max_length=10,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_('10-digit National ID number'),
    )

    mobile_number = models.CharField(
        'Mobile Number',
        max_length=13,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text='13-digit mobile number including country code (+98)',
    )

    home_address = models.TextField(
        'home address',
        blank=True,
    )

    work_address = models.TextField(
        'work address',
        blank=True,
    )

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        permissions = (('can_verify_user', _('Can verify user')),)
```

With or without that custom form, everything else looks exactly the same as Django's default Admin site. It is only the `Password` field that changes.

Comment: Can you share your `CustomUser` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are overriding default User Admin form with CustomUserForm. If you want to handle this situation you have to handle password field in your form too like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

class CustomUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        label=("Password"),
        help_text=(
            "Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
            "this user's password, but you can change the password "
            "using <a href=\"../password/\">this form</a>."
        ),
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['national_id'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['mobile_number'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: All other elements in the default Admin site are displaying properly without me handling them in my custom user form and the password field should not be any different.

Comment: @OmidShojaee password is different from others just test it